# jmeter junit and log4j

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jmeter

I am running jmeter to run my test script with selenium using junit.

I had configured a log4j.properties(log to a location) for my junit script and it is working fine when i run it in  my IDE(intellij)

However, when i build it into jar and run it using jmeter's junit sampler, the log4j would not create the log in my assigned location.

What i am doing wrong here? when i unzip into my jar, the log4j.properties is in the jar

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${user.home}/TEDTEST2.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%n
```

Comment: Hi thks for the reply. i have read thru the post, i am a novice when it comes to java, i could appreciate if anyone could simplify for me. i only have one set of log4j.properties in the root of my jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `log4j.conf` within /bin folder of your JMeter installation. I guess that you should move your logging configuration there.

Also there is `-L` key. According to documentation

> -L, --loglevel =
>                   [category=]level e.g. jorphan=INFO or jmeter.util=DEBUG

By the way, there is a [WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) plugin which can make things easier. It's pretty simple to configure and it provides logging combined with JMeter via `WDS.log()` function.

Comment: Thks Dmitri! It worked, i basically have to use the log4j.conf in the /bin of jmeter